# python string of a list weird output

Tags: python, string, list

How does the following output come?

```
>>> a
'hello'
>>> a = list(a)  
>>> a
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
>>> a = str(a)
>>> a
"['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']"
>>> a.title()
"['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O']"
>>> a[0]
'['
>>> a[1]
"'"
>>> a[2]
'h'
```

When title has to capitalize only the first letter of the string, how does every letter get capitalized?

Comment: You created a list. Then the string conversion of the list. What output did you expect instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Either there should be no change, or only 'h' should be capitalized. Isn't that how title works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused about how `title` works.

```
In [5]: s = "hello there"

In [6]: s.title()
Out[6]: 'Hello There'
```

See how it capitalises the first letter of each word? When you `str()` the list, it no longer sees `hello` as a single word. Instead, it sees each letter on its own and decides to capitalise each letter.

Answer (score 5):

`str()` does not join a list of individual characters back together into a single string. You'd use `str.join()` for that:

```
>>> a = list('hello')
>>> ''.join(a)
'hello'
```

`str(listobject)` returns a string representation of the list object, not the original string you converted to a list. The string representation is a debug tool; text you can, for the most part, paste back into a Python interpreter and have it recreate the original data.

If you wanted to capitalise just the first characters, use `str.title()` *directly on the original string*:

```
>>> 'hello'.title()
'Hello'
>>> 'hello world'.title()
'Hello World'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a=list('hello')
>>> str(a)
"['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']"
>>> len(str(a))
25
```

So you have a string of 25 characters. All those `'`,`,` etc. are part of the string. `title` sees 5 one-character words, so each one is upper cased. Try `''.join` instead

```
>>> ''.join(a)
'hello'
>>> len(''.join(a))
5
>>> ''.join(a).title()
'Hello'
```